# Count null values using CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, if-statement, count, case

I am trying to count the number of missing postal codes using CASE to flag null values as 1, otherwise 0.

```
 CASE WHEN ([postcode]=NULL)
 THEN 1
 ELSE 0 END AS pc_missing
```

Even though I know there are lots of missing data, none of them receive the value of 1.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: `[postcode] IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

`null` is not a value - it's the lack of a value. `null` returns "unknown" (which is not `true`) when evaluated against any value operator - `=`, `!=`, `>`, `<`, etc. Instead, you should check it with the `is [not] null` operator:

```
 CASE WHEN ([postcode] IS NULL)
 THEN 1
 ELSE 0 END AS pc_missing
```